# Not able to connect to iothub using device connection string - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect 100 mqtt clients to iothub using jmeter.

In  mqtt connection panel, for pwd, am using iothubowner connection string (available in shared access policy page in azure portal), from which SAS get generated & using the same in pwd for all 100 clients.

connection is successful as well.

but when i try to use the respective client connection string, from which SAS get generated using device explorer, get applied in pwd  and  the connection get failed.

Any help pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am not sure still why respective connection string is creating props, but in such case, the recommended solution is to use iothubowner connection string from the shared access policy page. It's quite successful.

Answer (score 0):

JMeter executes Samplers upside down by each virtual user so you don't need to duplicate this Gateway Connect sampler, just define 2 threads (virtual users) in the Thread Group and each thread (virtual user) will execute Gateway Connect sampler and establish its own connection with the broker.

The credentials can be parameterized using i.e. CSV Data Set Config so each virtual user would connect with its own username/password combination

More information: Testing the MQTT Messaging Broker for IoT - A Guide

Comment: I dont see any relevant in above answer, to question what been asked. The question talks about iothubowner connection string Vs device connection string.